# Why does only the show() operation show up in the spark ui?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-ui

I currently have a project using spark. For this project we are calculating some averages on a `DataSet` as follows:

```
public void calculateAverages() {
    this.data.show();
    String format = "HH";

    // Get the dataset such that the time column only contains the hour. 
    Dataset<Row> df = this.data.withColumn("Time", functions.from_unixtime(functions.col("Time").divide(1000), format));

    df.show();

    // Group rows by the hour (HH).
    RelationalGroupedDataset df_grouped = df.groupBy("Time");

    // Calculate averages for each column.
    Dataset<Row> df_averages = df_grouped.agg(
            functions.avg(column_names[0]),
            functions.avg(column_names[1]),
            functions.avg(column_names[2]),
            functions.avg(column_names[3]),
            functions.avg(column_names[4]),
            functions.avg(column_names[5]),
            functions.avg(column_names[6])
        );

    // Order the rows from 00 to 24. 
    Dataset<Row> df_ordered = df_averages.orderBy(functions.asc("Time"));
    
    // Show in console. 
    df_ordered.show();
}
```

Here `this.data` is defined as `Dataset<PowerConsumptionRow> data` where `PowerConsumptionRow` is a custom class.

For this code I was expecting the operations `groupBy`, `agg` and `orderBy` to show up as stages in the spark user interface. However, as can be seen below, only the `show()` operations are showing:

[image: Spark ui]

Is there a reason why these operations are not showing up ? The operations are all performed successfully since the output of `show()` is correct.

Comment: PowerConsumptionRow is a custom - well you can only do what is defined for your class. And as we can not even guess what it looks like, an answer would be pure speculation.

Comment: `this.data` is mapped to `Dataset<Row>` which represents a [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html).

Comment: there are three jobs that are getting generated as per Spark UI. Spark creates jobs when there is an action called or any shuffle operation happen due to any wide transformation like join, groupBy etc. So you won't see that in the job description.